# My PI makes shut down at 22:15 regularly, but I don't know why

Tags: shutdown

I can find the entry in syslog:

```
Mar 29 22:15:01 raspi CRON[14533]: (root) CMD (   shutdown -h now )
```

But I can't find any related between the cron jobs of any users.

```
for user in $(cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd); do echo -n "$user: "; sudo crontab -u $user -l | grep shutdown; echo; done
```

Any Idea, how can I find the source of the shutdown reported by syslog?

Comment: Is there anything in `/etc/crontab`?

Comment: Oh yes, there is! I searched through the whole /etc/cron.d and didn't noticed crontab itself. Thank you!

Comment: Made it an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't find anything in the user's crontabs, it is very likely there's an entry in `/etc/crontab` that is kicking off the `shutdown` procedure.